# Play sound from any position on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, objective-c++

I have a "*.caf" file, I can play it, but I need progress of playing, and jump to any position of music track. How to implement it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer has property currentTime which can be use either for picking position

```
- (Float32)getProgressValue:(NSString*)section
{
return backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime;
}
```

or setting position

```
- (void) progressMusic:(Float32)progressMusic
{
[backgroundMusicPlayer setCurrentTime:progressMusic];   
}
```

then u can easily implement progress bar or UI Slider according this values.